# Jmeter CSV data config

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am running a JMeter test which requires me to use a test data dedicated for one user. Like unique once parameter setting in Loadrunner. Always the user 1  has to pick the same data for all the iteration.

Comment: hard code the data.  Or feed all the users from a queue, with the read from a queue only on the first iteration, using that same piece of data forever

Answer (score 0):

You can use i.e. [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) i.e. to read:

- 1st line from file for first user
- 2nd line from file for second user
- etc.

The relevant expression would be something like:

```
 ${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().get(ctx.getThreadNum()),)}
```

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about the concept of Groovy scripting in JMeter

Demo:

[image]

If it doesn't match your input data format you can consider using another combination of the aforementioned [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) and/or `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` JMeter Variable.

You might also be interested in [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) plugin.

Comment: Thanks..It worked.
 How do i ignore the first line in the CSV ?

Comment: It should ignore the first line automatically

Comment: Regular Expression
${__groovy(new File('ProductionIssueCards_New.csv').readLines().get(ctx.getThreadNum()),)}

i get a output as "SSN" which is the first line in the CSV file

Its not ignoring the first line in the CSV